# itunes 12.1 song into ringtone for iPhone

Tags: ios, itunes, ringtones

I can't save segment of song as AAC in order to use as ringtone. Stuck at that stage. I am using iTunes 12.1.0.05. There seem to be solutions for earlier iTunes versions. I've edited song to be 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric says, you need the file to be converted to .aac & have the extension .m4r.

It also needs to be 40 seconds or less in length.

OK, you could pay 50 bucks to do that - or you could do it for **free**.

Use [Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/) to cut to correct length & export as .aac

Then drop the file onto [MakeiPhoneRingtone](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) to convert it for the phone.

Drop the result onto iTunes & sync.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GarageBand ( on you iPhone will be best)

You can create a ringtone using the instruments and recoding features.

Open GarageBand.

- Click the (+) symbol to open a new Song

.

- Choose your instrument or sample.
- Play something you like while recording. (red button)
- Stop the recording when done. ( I assume you can do an edit if need
  be.)
- Click the button ( Triangle pointing down in the top of the menu bar)
  to go back to My Songs. The song will be saved.
- Click Select and select your song.
- Then click the share button ( Square with arrow pointing up)
- Choose Ring tone and follow the instructions.

On the iPhone if you just choose done at the end, the exported file will appear in your ringtones under sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box the iTunes will have save as MP3.

To change that to AAC, open iTunes preferences:

In the general tab click on the Import settings.

Select AAC

[image: aac]

Now  you will have the "Create AAC"

[image]

Thats it, the rest you know.